# Get CAML from LINQ to SharePoint

Tags: caml-query, linq

Is there an equilivant to [GetCommand](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/141435.aspx) in LINQ to SharePoint?  I know about ctx.Log, but I'm looking for something to retrieve the CAML from a LINQ statement *without* executing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as described in [How to: View CAML Generated by LINQ to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798464.aspx), you just need to access the [DataContext.Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.linq.datacontext.log.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to view your CAML query without deploying and executing the code, you can use [LINQPAD](http://www.linqpadupdates.net/LINQPad.exe) with the [SharePoint 2010 Data Context Driver](http://linqpadsp2010driver.codeplex.com/documentation) (from Codeplex). If you scroll down on the linked documentation page, you see that the CAML is generated under the SQL result tab.